# Sum of functions bounded between 0 and 1?

Tags: functions

Let $y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$. I'm looking for two functions $f,g$ such that
$$
f(x)+g(y) \in [0,1]
$$
Do they exist? In positive case, do you have suggestions for what $f$ and $g$ could be? I'm not interested in $f,g$ taking a constant value or period functions.

Comment: How about $f(x)=g(x)=\frac{|\sin x|}{2}$?

Comment: Take $f,g:x\longmapsto\dfrac12\tanh^2(x)$ or $f,g:x\longmapsto\dfrac12\mathrm{e}^{-x^2}$ or any functions with range included in $[0,1/2]$.

Comment: Why don't you just say what is it exactly that you want?.. :)

Comment: I wish I knew :) I want to model the probability of an event using an additive model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $\tanh$ is neither constant nor periodic and takes values in the open interval $\ ]{-1},1[\ $. By choosing the constants $c_1$, $c_2$ properly you can then fabricate many pairs of functions
$$f_i(x):=c_i\bigl(1+\tanh(\alpha_i x+\beta_i)\bigr)\qquad(i=1,2)$$
that suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=\biggl|\dfrac{\sin x}{2}\biggr|$, $g(y)=\biggl|\dfrac{\cos y}{2}\biggr|$ should work.

Answer (score -1):

What about $f(x)=g(x)=$$(-1)^x/2$?
$(tanh^2x/2)$ won't work because the range of $f+g$ is $[0,1)$, not $[0,1]$